# QPushButton & shortcut

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a problem with Qt 4.6.0 and shortcut for `QPushButtons` :

I want to display a special text in a `QTextEdit` when the user clicks a `button`, but only when the `button` is pressed, as soon as it's released, i want another text to come up.

Everything works fine but now I want to add a shortcut (let's say `F1`) to perform the exact same operation, when I push `F1` it displays something special in a `QTextEdit` 'til I release the `key`. How do I manage to do this ?

I added the shortCut on my `button`, but when I press `F1`, it's blinking, it's like as long as I press `F1`, lots of `signals` are being emitted... I want my `QTextEdit` to change when I press `F1` and then change back when I release the `key`...

I hope my question is clear !

Thanks a lot in advance for your advices !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most simple solution to this problem is to use `installEventFilter()` on the parent object (the window), and filter out the `QEvent::MouseButtonPress` and `QEvent::MouseButtonRelease` events.

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
 if (obj == textEdit) {
     if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
         QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
         qDebug() << "Ate key press" << keyEvent->key();
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 } else {
     // pass the event on to the parent class
     return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer ! You're right, I finally chose this solution, but something makes me think it's not a proper way to do... The thing is, the QPushButton is all setup up to react to other event in my application, and I have to "copy" those reaction for my shortcut... I think it's breaking the DRY principle and I don't really like it...
For example, at some point, my QPushButton is disabled, I don't want to do any work to disable the shortcut as well, since the shortcut should be a property of the QPushbutton, and therefore, should be off when the QPushButton is off.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't *feel* right, but I consider this custom behavior to be exotic to the nature of QPushButton (users expect it to do something when it is clicked once, not any reaction when they press the mouse key down without releasing it). I guess as long as you don't have to do this for a few hundred buttons, and it's not all over your application, this is a clean, and easily readable way of getting your button to behave as you wish.

Comment: Yeah I guess, it's correct that it's not a basic behavior of QPushButton... Anyway, I'll go with that solution... Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

A push button emits the signal clicked() when it is activated by the mouse, the Spacebar or by a keyboard shortcut. You'll have to handle key press and key release to do what you want.

Comment: Basically that's what I suggested in my answer earlier (see below).